# When is a lower gain transistor preferable? - Letter suffix on bipolar transistors

Tags: transistors, bjt

Some transistors are available with a letter suffix indicating hFE.

Eg. BC547 is available as (typ. @Ic = 2mA):
- A => 170
- B => 300
- C => 520

I understand why you would choose C, hFE being high sounds good as that is what we use a transistor for: amplification.

But why would I want to use an A postfixed transistor? Are there any good reasons to specifically using these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason would usually be price.  The manufacturing process for transistors results in considerable variation in gain.  The manufacturers test for this and "bin" the parts according to gain and possibly other parameters.  They can sell the better parts for more money.  So you chose the C grade when you need high gain and the A grade when the lower gain is good enough and you want to save a little.  In high volume applications the little savings can add up.

Comment: The overhead in my local electronics shop around the corner is mainly in the fact that someone needs to walk from the cash register to the right cabinet, count the transistors, drop them in a little paper bag and count my money. That would explain why I don't know about price difference, right?

Comment: If you are saying that --leaving aside price-- always, the higher the gain, the better, that is not true.

Comment: @Teleclavo: Yes, it largely is true.  Except for contrived example, in real circuits a transistor with higher gain is a superset of the same transistor with lower gain.  So yes, the distinction between the grades the OP asked about is effectively between price and gain.

Comment: These are just two examples of (very) real circuits for which an infinite gain in the transistor involved would be disastrous: a) The FET preamp inside every electret microphone. b) Most UHF amplifiers (http://www.ieee.li/pdf/essay/rf_power_amplifier_fundamentals.pdf Figs. 3.48 and 3.53)(http://www.intersil.com/data/an/an9315.pdf Figs. 2 and 7).

Comment: @Telaclavo: The electret preamps I have seen use a FET in source follower mode.  In that case higher gain is better and infinite gain would be ideal.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Most electret preamps have a JFET in COMMON SOURCE configuration, so an infinite transconductance would completely distort the signal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TF202C-D.PDF http://www.openmusiclabs.com/learning/sensors/electret-microphones/

Answer (score 1):

More hFE, and more gain, is not always desirable. Higher than appropriate gains, could cause:

- Instability.
- Saturation / distortion.
- Excess dissipation.
- (Some other effects).

Comment: excess dissipation?

Comment: I disagree.  Well designed transistor circuits work for a gain range of some minimum to infinity.  A transistor with higher than its minimum guarateed gain should still work.  Most transistors don't have a guaranteed max gain anyway.

Comment: @jippie More gain may easily imply more current through devices that dissipate more, the higher the current is.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I said could cause. For instance, too much gain in a feedback loop may cause instability. You don't want infinite gain, there.

Comment: But the gain of a single transistor shouldn't dictate the gain of of a feedback loop.

Comment: Instability due to high HFE = poor design. What about feedback?

Comment: Sounds like poor design if hFE and not passives in the feedback loop determines circuit gain. Wouldn't that vary with temperature, current, and part to part?

Comment: @OlinLathrop But it does dictate it, in some cases. For instance, in a transistor-based oscillator. A gain higher than the appropriate one will create excessive harmonics.

Comment: It is inadequate gain that will cause distortion, because the less gain you have, the less negative feedback you can apply to linearize the circuit. The higher the gain of the device, the more linear and distortion-free you can make the circuit. High gain means that the oscillations use a smaller, more linear range of operation of the device.  Transistor-based oscillators can put out sine waves even with high gain transistors. There has to be some feedback element that dynamically adjusts the closed loop gain to 1, like a thermistor (lamp filament) etc.